# Composer replaced existing files

Tags: git, composer-php

After (git) cloning an existing Magento project (symphony - PHP) I user the 
composer install command. But after that is done my git tels me there are 5K+ file changes. I looked them up and these are just files that are replaced by composer.

How can I change that composer doesn't replace those files. The .gitignore file is provided by Magento so the issue shouldn't be with that file.

Comment: What is the output of this command `git diff | head`. Does it changed anything inside the files? Or maybe just some permissions were changed on all the files?

Comment: Oh I got a warning:  LF will be replaced by CRLF in <filename> So I gues this is beceause of windows. Is there a way you can prevent Windows from doing  that?

Comment: Do you have `vendor` directory under version control?

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account your comment you could say git that you'd like to have CRLF in your working directory:

```
git config --local core.autocrlf true
```

You could read more about that setting in [the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-coreautocrlf).